# Pandas: Group start/end events into intervals

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have the following data:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "id": [1,1,1,2,1,2],
    "datetime": [
        pd.to_datetime("2020-01-01"),
        pd.to_datetime("2020-01-02"),
        pd.to_datetime("2020-01-03"),
        pd.to_datetime("2020-01-04"),
        pd.to_datetime("2020-01-04"),
        pd.to_datetime("2020-01-06"),
        ],
    "type": [
        "start",
        "end",
        "start",
        "start",
        "end",
        "end"
    ]
})
```

which looks like this

```
    pid datetime    type
0   1   2020-01-01  start
1   1   2020-01-02  end
2   1   2020-01-03  start
3   2   2020-01-04  start
4   1   2020-01-04  end
5   2   2020-01-06  end
```

and I would like to group them in a way that for each pid, a combination of start and closest end dates are grouped in one row. Note that each pid may occur multiple times. So desired result would be:

```
pid  start_date  end_date
1   2020-01-01  2020-01-02
1   2020-01-03  2020-01-04
2   2020-01-04  2020-01-06
```

First approach that came to my mind is looping and perform element-wise matching but that seems quite inefficient to me. Especially because the dataframe has >1m entries.
Next thing was a pandas groupby, but I could not find any similar use cases.

Is there a more efficient way to group the data as I described it?

Comment: I don't think anything in Pandas will be efficient on 1m data points, Show us what you tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One idea is create counter by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and then use [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df['g'] = df.groupby('type').cumcount()

df = (df.pivot(['g','id'], 'type','datetime')[['start','end']]
        .add_suffix('_date')
        .reset_index(level=0, drop=True))
print (df)
type start_date   end_date
id                        
1    2020-01-01 2020-01-02
1    2020-01-03 2020-01-04
2    2020-01-04 2020-01-06
```

Comment: but I think this approach would fail if you have 3 ids...could be (1, start) (2, start) (3 start) (2, end), then `cumcount` would be 0,1,2,0 but it's unknown to which id the group relates...if that makes sense ?

Comment: @bk_ - ya, it seems more complicated, is possible change data sample with this?

Answer (score 1):

Try `groupby` and `agg` with `shift`:

```
df.groupby(["id", df["type"].eq(df["type"].shift(-1))])["datetime"].agg(
    start_date="first", end_date="last"
).reset_index(level=0).reset_index(drop=True)

   id start_date   end_date
0   1 2020-01-01 2020-01-02
1   1 2020-01-03 2020-01-04
2   2 2020-01-04 2020-01-06
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

with the help of @jezraels answer, I found a semi-efficient way which gets the job done in 1-2 minutes:

```
result_records = []
df.sort_values(by="datetime", ascending=True, inplace=True)

for id in df.id.unique():
    df_single_id = df.loc[df["id"]==id].copy()

    df_single_id['g'] = df.groupby('type').cumcount()

    df_single_id = df_single_id.pivot(index="g",
                                      columns="type")
    
    # merge hierarchical columns to flat
    df_single_id.columns = [f'{i}_{j}' for i,j in df_single_id.columns]

    result_records.extend(df_single_id.to_dict('records'))

result_df = pd.Dataframe.from_dict(result_records)
```

I'm sure theres a better way to do that, but in this case this solution is enough.